# Which const with which reference will change the argument and create an const object?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, reference, stl

I have this template call:

```
int ia[] = { 9, 2, 5, 1, 8 };
const sav<int> sia( ia, sizeof( ia ) / sizeof( ia[ 0 ] ) );
```

And I want to sort  the `ia`, and create `sia`. I tried like this:

```
template<typename T>
class sav {
public:
    sav(T& givenArray,size_t size) {
         for( int idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
            data.push_back(givenArray[idx]);
         }
         std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
         for(int idx =0; idx<size; ++idx){
            givenArray[idx] = data.at(idx);
         }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

But I don't know where I have to write `const` in this case to get this code to work.

Comment: You don't have different constructors for this case, you only have a single constructor. The object `cmt` is constant, and the object `mt` is not, even if both are constructed the same way with the same constructor.

Comment: You are declaring functions, not classes. Function don't have a *constructor*.

Comment: @Ripi2 I think hes declaring an instance of my_template<int> and a const instance, both with arguments (iam,size) to the constructor..

Comment: @Ripi2 I have the template class `my_template`, and in that I want these constructors...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude are you sure? I tried but didn't worked for me with only one constructor. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @rmawatson I see. The lack of a mcve messed me.

Comment: You really have to show us  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and tell us *what* errors you get (copy-pasted as text, in full and complete).

Comment: @kortealma Is, by chance, that you want two different ctors, one able to modify some parameter (e.g. the array) and the other ctor unable?

Comment: @Ripi2 In both cases I want to modify some parameters. But, the `cmt` I want to be const in the main program.

Comment: @kortealma so make it const. what's the problem? It's const in your first posted line, how does that *not* do what you want?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited my question with my attempts.

Comment: change `T&` to `T*`

Comment: @M.M WOW lot of thanks, can you write mi a bit why? I thought there I must get it as an reference not as a pointer. But, anyway write your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make this code work is to change `T&` to `T*`.

You are "passing" the array by actually passing a pointer to its first element, and also passing the length separately.

It would also be possible to pass the array by reference (in which case you do not need the separate length parameter, since the length is party of the array's type.

I'm not sure what you are talking about with the "const" discussion.